# how to build uuid ossp for postgres on ubuntu 14 installing openbravo

Tags: ubuntu, uuid

I am facing a problem while executing the `ant install.source` command.
SQL is working fine it's just a single error that I am facing:

```
**> SQL Command failed with: ERROR: could not access file
> "$libdir/uuid-ossp": No such file or directory**
```

I've downloaded the uuid but how to compile it??
or how to get over this error??

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't installed extensions. If you have installed the postgres from source, go to postgres contrib directory and run the following commands

1. make
2. make install

It will install all extensions